# Loss turns to be NAN at the first round step in my tensorflow CNN

Tags: nan, tensorflow, loss

Loss  turns to be NAN at the first round step in  my tensorflow CNN.

**1. Network** :

3 hidden layers (2 convolutional layers +1 hidden fullconnect layer) + readout layer.

**2. The 3 hidden layers** :

*a) Weights* :
`W = tf.Variable(tf.truncated_normal(wt,stddev=0.1,name='wights' ))`

*b) Bias* :
`b = tf.Variable( tf.fill([W.get_shape().as_list()[-1] ],0.9),name = 'biases' )`

*c) Activition:*
`ReLu`

*d) Dropout:*
`0.6`

**loss turns to be nan even if dropout is 0.0

**3. Readout layyer:**
`softmax`

**4: loss function:**
`tf.reduce_mean(-tf.reduce_sum(_lables * tf.log(_logist), reduction_indices=[1]))`

**5.optimizer:**
`tf.train.AdamOptimizer`

`learning_rate = 0.0005`
**loss truns to be nan even  if learning_rate = 0

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since we don't have the entire source code, it's hard to see the problem. However, you may try to use 'tf.nn.softmax_cross_entropy_with_logits' in your cost function. For example:

```
cost = tf.reduce_mean(tf.nn.softmax_cross_entropy_with_logits(predictions, labels))
```

You can find an entire code example using 'tf.nn.softmax_cross_entropy_with_logits' at https://github.com/nlintz/TensorFlow-Tutorials.

Comment: thanks<br>, it fixed with two steps:<br>1.  use xavier_initializer  for weigths.  <br> 2. cost = tf.reduce_mean(tf.nn.softmax_cross_entropy_with_logits(predictions, labels)

Comment: @user6223071 awesome! Could you also share the xavier_initializer part for others if you don't mind?

Comment: xavier was  implemented in tensorflow api v8.0. here is [https://www.tensorflow.org/versions/r0.8/api_docs/python/contrib.layers.html#xavier_initializer]

Answer (score 1):

So far I've hit two cases where `nan` can result:

- The numbers get too large (perhaps you're performing `square` on a number, and the result is too large)
- Or there exists an invalid input (some functions like `sqrt` and `log` don't take negative inputs, so they would return `nan`)